# What is the format for Congressional Districts for reading in Tableau

Tags: database, tableau-api

I know Tableau has mapping support for mapping congressional districts, but how do I do it? I currently have two fields in my table: [STATE] and [DISTRICT_NO].

I created a custom field that combines the two:

[STATE] + " " + STR([DISTRIC_NO])

which produces strings like: CA 2, IL 1, AZ 3.

I formatted the custom field to have a Geographic Role: Congressional District.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a lot of Tableau Help files that show what mapping capabilities and I actually found one that provides an example! http://onlinehelp.tableausoftware.com/v8.0/pro/online/en-us/maps_geographicroles.html

> U.S. Congressional District names. Boundaries are determined by data provided by each state's redistricting commission. Examples: 1st District, 2, District 3, 4th

It's still quite vague, but I got it to work by:

1. Setting the number part, [DISTRICT_NO] as having a Geographic Role: Congressional District
2. Creating a hierarchy that comprises [STATE] and [DISTRICT_NO]

Comment: Well done.  I'm glad you figured it out as well as shared with the rest of us.